# Firebase Authentication problen when i use mobile browser to login using Facebook login

Tags: reactjs, authentication, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I've created a Facebook firebase login using firebase hooks. It's working on PC/Laptop chrome and other browsers. But when I try to use any mobile browser, like chrome, operamini, uc browser, the facebook authentication page automatically closed and rejects login. How do I fix these issues?

Answer (score -2):

Maximum browser has an options that is "Pop-ups and redirects" if we block this options sometimes Facebook authentication Won't work properly